# Сверстать border почтовый конверт

Tags: html, css

Есть какая-то возможность сверстать такой border или тут только перекрывать фон формой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее это не бордер, а повторяющая картинка, на которой сверху фон. Но вообще это можно сделать на пример через `repeating-linear-gradient`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для тех кому интересно.

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.clearfix {
 content: '';
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

.form__wrapper {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 540px;
 height: 265px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;

 background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #f02755 0px, #f02755 10px, 
                              #fff 10px, #fff 20px, 
                              #55a5d6 20px, #55a5d6 30px, 
                              #fff 30px, #fff 40px);
}

.main-form {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0 35px;
 padding-top: 33px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.main-form input {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 163px;
 margin-bottom: 14px;
 padding: 10px 0;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(236, 236, 236, 1),
       inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(236, 236, 236, 1);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #064f7a;
 outline: none
}

.main-inputs,
.secondary-inputs {
 width: 50%;
}

.main-inputs {
 float: left;
}

.secondary-inputs {
 float: right;
}

*::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #064f7a;
 opacity: 1;
}

*:-moz-placeholder {
 color: #064f7a;
 opacity: 1;
}

*::-moz-placeholder {
 color: #064f7a;
 opacity: 1;
}

*:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: #064f7a;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="form__wrapper">
 <form class="main-form clearfix">
  <div class="main-inputs">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Web">
  </div>
  <div class="secondary-inputs">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Message">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну полоски вы сделали, но тс явно спрашивал про такую обводку вокруг формы...

Comment: я и есть тс) мне интересен был сам результат, за border я уточнил просто

Comment: хахах, блин, и действительно) ну да, я не особо внимателен. А так - почему вариант с полосатой подложкой под формой не подходит?

Comment: в том то и дело что подходит, почему-то сперва взглянув на форму пришло в голову, что это border

Comment: @selya подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать перенос текста в message на следующий инпут? возможно тут бы подошел тег <textarea>, но мне нужны бордеры, как на скрине. есть идеи по этому поводу?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665159/how-can-i-underline-all-rows-in-textarea?__=643858106?

Answer (score 0):

Для border можно задать изображение: 
http://css-live.ru/articles-css/razbiraemsya-s-border-image-iz-css3.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator

Поддерживается неплохо, не работает в IE10-:
https://caniuse.com/#search=Border-image